# JMeter: How to run test with rate of n concurrent requests per second

Tags: jmeter

I would like to run the test with the given execution rate per second. The next iteration should start asynchronously at 2nd second without waiting for completion of first iteration.
I tried with Constant Throughput Timer but it doesn't proceed to next iteration until
it finish getting response of first iteration threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 separate [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for this (make sure that you have `Run Thread Groups Consecutively` box unchecked at [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level.

Also check your [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) configuration `Calculate Throughput based on` field, you may wish to have separate timer for each Thread Group.

By the way, there is more advanced [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) element available via plugin which provides easy-readable graph demonstrating the load pattern.

If you will be considering using separate Thread Groups remember that JMeter Variables have scope local to the Thread Group where they are defined. To use them across different Thread Groups you'll need to cast them to JMeter Properties which have "global" scope. See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide for how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

A single thread can only handle one request at a time. You'll need more than one thread for what you're asking for. The constant throughput timer can indeed do what you're asking as long as you have enough threads.

In order to achieve what you're asking for (lets say 1 request every second, regardless of how long the request takes) you could I would suggest using a large number of threads and using the CTT for 60 requests per second.

Comment: I have started 300 threads i.e Number of Threads=300 and Ramp-Up period=1 (300/sec). Is this correct? Still it doesn't work